# Lever in deep space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation

Can you tell me where my logic goes wrong below?

1. Lever on Earth: if I drop down mass *2m* at distance *d* from fulcrum a certain amount *h* (i.e. velocity *v* and KE *mv<sup>2</sup>*), then it will lift mass *m* at distance *2d* from fulcrum a distance of *2h* in the same time (i.e. velocity *2v* and KE *2mv<sup>2</sup>*).  Let's keep *h* small wrt *d* to ignore curvature.  The upward mass *m* has twice as much velocity and kinetic energy as the downward mass *2m*.  The extra kinetic energy of the upward mass is balanced out by its gravitational potential energy.
2. Lever in deep space:  Will the same thing happen in deep space?  Will the mass *m* object keep going at velocity *2v* if the lever releases it and doesn't hold on to it?
3. Where is all the extra kinetic energy coming from?  Who is providing the potential energy since we are in deep space far from any gravity?
4. What if I put mass *2m* or *3m* instead of mass *m* at distance *2d* (assuming the level is strong enough to handle the stress)?  Will it also get launched at velocity *2v*?

I am looking for a big picture answer of what happens at the end of the day.  The details of what happens to the lever atoms and molecules is all well and good but it must explain the final result where all this extra kinetic energy comes from.

P.S.  A similar scenario would be to turn the lever on its side and do the experiment with horizontal movement, effectively making gravity irrelevant.

Closing Comment: After comments exchange with @Allure and @ThePhoton I think I understand what's going on.  In deep space, the initial mass *2m* had to arrive with a velocity > *v* because, as soon as it hit the lever, it started slowing down and had to push itself as well as the lever arm.  For the combined movement to be *h* the initial KE must have been > *mv<sup>2</sup>*.  I didn't do the detailed calculations but I am satisfied that the incoming mass *2m* supplied all the kinetic energy, some or all of which was imparted to the departing mass *m* through the lever.

Comment: Twice the velocity means 4x the kinetic energy, not 2x.

Comment: Yes but the mass is half so its KE is twice that of the 2m object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Lever on Earth: if I drop down mass 2m at distance d from fulcrum a certain amount h (i.e. velocity v and KE mv2), then it will lift mass m at distance 2d from fulcrum a distance of 2h in the same time (i.e. velocity 2v and KE 2mv2).

This is only true if all of the kinetic energy initially in the first mass is transferred to the second mass. This occurs only in a perfectly elastic collision, and then only in this special case where the moments of inertia of the two masses about the fulcrum of the lever are equal.

If the collision is anything but perfectly elastic, the final velocity of the short end of the lever will be less than the initial falling velocity of the first mass (which you have called *v*)

> ... Let's keep h small wrt d to ignore curvature. The upward mass m has twice as much velocity

This is only true if the collision of the first mass onto the lever is perfectly inelastic. If the collision is inelastic, then kinetic energy is not conserved --- some of the energy must be converted into shock waves in the surrounding material or used up deforming the colliding objects.

So you can't have both all of the k.e. from the first object being transferred into the second one, and the velocity of the second object being equal to twice the initial velocity of the first object, because one requires a perfectly elastic collision (and nicely balanced masses of the two objects, which you happen to have assumed), and the other requires a perfectly inelastic collision.

In the case of an (ideal or partially) elastic collision, the first mass will bounce back from the lever after striking it, so you must account for it retaining some kinetic energy after the collision.

In all cases (ideal elastic, partially elastic or ideally inelastic) angular momentum will be conserved. You will use conservation of momentum and whatever you assume about the elasticity of the collision to set up the equations to find the final velocities of the two masses.

> Will the same thing happen in deep space? Will the mass m object keep going at velocity 2v if the lever releases it and doesn't hold on to it?

Again this depends on whether the collision of the first object onto the lever is perfectly elastic, perfectly inelastic, or somewhere in between. The maximum final velocity of the second object is if the collision is perfectly elastic. The minimum final velocity of the second object occurs if the collision is perfectly inelastic. Any other final velocity between those values is also possible.

> 3. Where is all the extra kinetic energy coming from?

There is no extra kinetic energy. The final kinetic energy of the second mass will be equal or less than the initial kinetic energy of the first mass.

This is true regardless of whether this happens in a gravitational field or not. We can assume the collision between the first mass and the lever happens in an instant, and that there is no time for the force of gravity to affect the velocities of the objects or the lever in the instant after the collision.

Answer (score 3):

> Lever in deep space: Will the same thing happen in deep space? Will the mass m object keep going at velocity 2v if the lever releases it and doesn't hold on to it?

In deep space, the mass of $2m$ does not exert any force on the lever because it has no weight, so nothing happens.

Comment: That's a good answer

Comment: Let's say the *2m* mass is already traveling at *v* when it hits the lever at distance *d*.  It's momentum will push the lever and the other end of the lever will have no choice but to propel the mass *m* at velocity *2v*.  Presumably the original mass *2m* will come to a stop after transferring its momentum to the lever, but the other mass *m* now took off at twice the KE.

Comment: @Jay *the other end of the lever will have no choice but to propel the mass m at velocity 2v* How are you getting this? The force might be 2x, but it doesn't mean the mass will move at $2v$, because work done = force * distance. You can have twice the force, and not necessarily twice the velocity.

Comment: As long as the lever stays rigid and doesn't bend, then a lateral movement of *h* at distance *d* on one side of the fulcrum will result in a movement *2h* at distance *2d* on the other side.  This is trivial geometry, no physics needed.  These movements occur *in the same amount of time* so the velocity of the other mass will be *2v*.

Comment: @Jay But can you be sure the first mass will move by $d$? Why can't it move by $d/2$ and then come to a stop?

Comment: @Allure it doesn't matter how much the initial mass moves.  The point is that the other mass (*m* at distance *2d*) will move *twice* that lateral distance *in the same amount of time* getting *twice the velocity* and *twice the kinetic energy* (because it has half the mass).   Where did the extra kinetic energy come from?

Comment: @Jay, from whatever is applying force to the lever.

Comment: @ThePhoton the force is supplied by the initial mass *2m* arriving at the lever with velocity *v* and KE *mv^2*.  At the end of the interaction, the other mass *m* leaves with velocity *2v* and KE *2mv^2*.  Everything is in the reference frame of the lever.  No other actors are involved.  No gravity is involved.

Comment: @Jay, this is the first that you've mentioned the first mass being in motion and striking the lever. Your question says "I push down...", implying there is something ("you") applying a force to the lever.

Comment: In this new scenario you should say whether when the first mass strikes the lever, is the collision is an elastic or inelastic collision. If it is an elastic collision, then the first object must bounce away from the lever and only part of its k.e. will be transferred to the 2nd object. If it is an inelastic collision, then energy is not conserved --- some is converted to sound or absorbed by deformation of the masses or the lever. In none of these scenarios does the 2nd object end up with more k.e. than the first object started with.

Comment: @ThePhoton the 'push down' scenario was on Earth and I really should have said 'I drop down'.  There is no problem there because the Earth's gravity provides the potential energy to balance everything out.  The second scenario was in deep space and I realize I did not word my scenario correctly to indicate that there is nothing else.

Comment: @Jay, you can edit your question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks,  I have edited the question and added a closing comment about the incoming kinetic energy into the system.